# Having trouble console.log anything from this API, we're not allowed to use JQuery or Bootstrap, so I have to use fetch and bulma

Tags: javascript, arrays, api, console.log

so I've been having trouble trying to get anything to console.log from this API, the most I can get is a null or undefined return. I've tried just the base statement from the API company, and the code snippet runs for them but for some reason won't even return a console.log for me. not sure if it's a problem on their end or mine because it seems to run fine on their website. also as I said in the title, I have to use fetch

EDIT: I'm in coding school right now so I'm pretty new to all of this

EDIT: the dashboard shows that the API is being called, so why am I not getting any responses?

EDIT: I figured it out, the API wasn't working

```
  // global variables
var countryInput = document.querySelector("#ipt-country");
var submitButton = document.querySelector("#submit-btn");
var currencyDisplay = document.querySelector("#currency-display");
// country currency array codes
var countryCurrencyArray =[ list off all countries with iso code for currency goes here, not going to list it bc its 270 lines long
];

    // begins exchange rate function
function getExchangeRate() {
    // grab data attribute
    var countrySearch = countryInput.value.toLowerCase().trim();
    var currencyUSA = "USD";
    var countryCurrency = "AUD";
    // var countryCurrency = countryInput.value.countryCurrencyArray[i];

    // if else errors
    if (countrySearch.length < 1) {
        return(null); 
    } else {
        var countryConversion = countryCurrencyArray.find(
            (element) => element.name === countrySearch)
    }

    if (countryConversion === void 0) {
        return(null);
    } else {
        var countryCurrency = countryConversion.code;
    }

    // fetch API to change currency rate from American Dollar (USD) to selected currency

    fetch(
        'https://currency-converter5.p.rapidapi.com/currency/convert?' + 
        '&from=' + currencyUSA + 
        '&to=' + countryCurrency +
        '&amount=1', 
        {
        "method": "GET",
        "headers": {
            "x-rapidapi-host": "currency-converter5.p.rapidapi.com",
            "x-rapidapi-key": "API-KEY"
        },
    }).then(response => {
        console.log(response);
    })
    .then(function(response) {
        response.json().then(function(data){
            for (i=0; i < data.response.countryCurrency.length; i++) {
                var exchangeMoney = document.createElement("div");
                exchangeMoney.classList.add(
                    "is-flex-mobile",
                    "column",
                    "has-text-centered",
                    "is-justify-content-space-evenly"
                );
                var exchangeOutput = document.createElement("div");
                exchangeRateOutput.classList.add("level-item");
                exchangeRateOutput.innerText = data.response.countryCurrency[i].code;
                exchangeRateMoney.appendChild(exchangeOutput);

                console.log(exchangeOutput);
            }
        });
    
    }).catch(err => {
        console.error('Request Failed', err);
    });

}    

getExchangeRate();

console.log(getExchangeRate());

submitButton.addEventListener("click", getExchangeRate);
```

Comment: You don't include `#` in the ID when you call `document.getElementById()`. It's only used with `document.querySelector()`.

Comment: Why do you need `targetCurrencyText`? It's the same as `currencyDisplay`. You also never use the variable.

Comment: `dataType` and `success` are not valid fetch options. Those are from jquery.

Comment: and if it's jsonp you're expecting, then JSON.parse is going to return false.